# Today + had been

Tags: past-perfect

I've seen a random tweet today but it left me puzzled. It said:

"Today had been "reading books and listening to loud music" kind of a day."

The user's description said he was from Chicago. I'm wondering why he decided to use past perfect. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: To me it suggests that this sentence is setting the scene for a following description of something that changed the kind of day. On its own, it suggests that there is a "But now ... " that is not being expressed.

Comment: We can't tell you 'why' without more context; we can only guess. Use of the perfect, whether present or past, is **always** dependent on context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Past perfect is not correct here.  It should be present perfect progressive. i.e.:

> "Today **has** been **a** "reading books and listening to loud music" kind of a day."

It seems most likely that this is a simple typing mistake by the original tweeter but one can use past perfect if the situation has changed.  e.g.:

> "Today **had** been **a** "reading books and listening to loud music" kind of a day until you called."

Comment: I think the "typing mistake" theory is quite plausible, considering 'd' and 's' are right next to each other on a keyboard.